# uncaught exception: error: { "$err" : "not master and slaveOk=false", "code" : 13435 }

Tags: mongodb

After running `db.getMongo().setSlaveOk()`; still below error is coming while I am accessing collections from secondery node. As per my understanding I should able see its data from secondary node.

`uncaught exception: error: { "$err" : "not master and slaveOk=false", "code" : 13435 }`

I have used below command to create replica set

```
mkdir D:\data\repdb\One mkdir D:\data\repdb\The mkdir D:\data\repdb\Two mongod --port 27017 --dbpath D:\data\repdb\One --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 mongod --port 27018 --dbpath D:\data\repdb\The --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 mongod --port 27019 --dbpath D:\data\repdb\Two --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 mongo --port 27017 rsconf = { "_id" : "rs0", "version" : 1, "members" : [ { "_id" : 1, "host" : "localhost:27017" } ] }

rs.initiate( rsconf )

rs.conf()

rs.add("localhost:27018") rs.add("localhost:27019")
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Yes .Its working now .Thanks Rishi fro your prompt answer.

Comment: Now I can see data on secondary using below :SECONDARY> db.book.find().count()  Again I insert one row inside primary and its count reaches say 4 but its not reflecting then in secondary until re connect once again ..Why this ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try: `rs.slaveOk()` on the Secondary member?